# Rearranging order of albums displayed in category show page

Tags: html, ruby

Ok this is going to be a bit long-winded so bear with me.

I have my album index page displaying all my albums, I can re order them based on the time created and the likes. my code for doing this is as follows (just ignore that some stuff is commented out, i havent yet figured out how to do weekly top like and all-time top likes, but thats another issue for another post)

```
# album.rb
    scope :latest, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
    #scope :weekly,    -> { order(likes: :desc) }
    #scope :alltime,   -> { order(likes: :desc) }

    def self.sort_by(sort_param)
        case sort_param
        when 'latest'
            latest
        #when 'weekly'
            #weekly
        #when 'alltime'
            #alltime
        else
            latest
        end
    end
```

```
#album controller
  def index
    @albums = Album.sort_by(params[:order])
  end
```

```
#album index
<table>
  <tbody>
    <%= link_to "Latest", albums_path(order: :latest) %><br>
    <%= link_to "Weekly Top", albums_path(order: :weekly) %><br>
    <%= link_to "All-Time Top", albums_path(order: :alltime) %>
  </tbody
</table>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <% @albums.each do |album| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to album.name, album %></td>
        <td><%= link_to image_tag(album.cover_image.variant(resize: "200x200")), album %></td>
        <td><%#= album.videos #%></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

ok so like I aid that has all worked as expected and changes the order of my albums in the album index page based off whichever link is selected... now onto my actual issue, I have all albums tied to a category. When I go into my categories and select one it takes me to the category show page for that category and displays all albums that fall within that specific category, great!. Now what im struggling with is how can I reorder the albums within the category show page like I did in the album index page above?

I have tried a few different combinations of things but unable to make it work. Here is what I have so far

```
#category.rb
    scope :latest, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
    #scope :weekly,    -> { order(likes: :desc) }
    #scope :alltime,   -> { order(likes: :desc) }

    def self.sort_by(sort_param)
        case sort_param
        when 'latest'
            latest
        #when 'weekly'
            #weekly
        #when 'alltime'
            #alltime
        else
            latest
        end
    end
```

```
#category controller
  def show
    @categories = Category.sort_by(params[:order])
  end
```

```
#category show
<table>
  <tbody>
    <%= link_to "Latest", categories_path(order: :latest) %><br>
    <%= link_to "Weekly Top", categories_path(order: :weekly) %><br>
    <%= link_to "All-Time Top", categories_path(order: :alltime) %>
  </tbody
</table>

<table>
    <tbody>
    <% @category.albums.map.each do |album| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= link_to album.name, album %></td>
            <td><%= link_to image_tag(album.cover_image.variant(resize: "200x200")), album %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So Im pretty sure I have it wrong in the category controller part, as well as the paths im calling in the show page.

Also im not even sure if I had to put the code in the Category model or if I would be able to call the code from the Album model as I am trying to re-order the albums in the category show page.

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `likes` is an integer column:

In order to get albums and categories created this week you'll need to define scopes like this:

```rb
scope :weekly, -> { where("created_at <= ?", DateTime.current.beginning_of_the_week) }
scope :latest,    -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
scope :by_likes,    -> { order(likes: :desc) }
```

Notice that "weekly" is not really an order but a filter. When you won't apply it you'll get "all the time".

Now in the views you can do:

```
    <%= link_to "Latest", categories_path(order: :latest) %><br>
    <%= link_to "Weekly Top", categories_path(weekly: true, order: :by_likes) %><br>
    <%= link_to "All-Time Top", categories_path(order: :by_likes) %>
```

and the analogical thing for the albums.

Now in the controllers you can do:

```rb
# categories controller
  def show
    @categories = Category.find(params[:id])

    @albums = @category.albums

    @albums = @albums.weekly if params[:weekly]

    @albums = @albums.by_likes if params[:order] == "by_likes"
    @albums = @albums.latest if params[:order] == "latest"
  end
```

```rb
# albums controller
  def index
    @albums = Album.all

    @albums = @albums.weekly if params[:weekly]

    @albums = @albums.by_likes if params[:order] == "by_likes"
    @albums = @albums.latest if params[:order] == "latest"
  end
```

And then you can just use the `@albums` variable in the category show view like this:

```
@albums.each do |album|
```

Comment: the line "@albums = @category.albums.sort_by(params[:order])" is throwing an error. "wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)". I do not think you have provided the right answer for my problem because beyond this error you have not addressed the "<%= link_to "Latest", categories_path(order: :latest) %>" lines which im sure have the wrong paths in them.

Comment: I THINK the only part thats not working properly is the paths in my category show view ex "link_to "Latest", categories_path(order: :latest) when i click on "Latest" it just takes me back to the categories INDEX page ( because the path is categories_path). ive tried stuff like "<%= link_to "Latest", categories_path(@category, order: :latest) %><br>" but I am just struggling with which parameter i need to pass into that path in place of "@category" in the line above, in order to return me to the same category id show page I was on when i clicked "Latest" or whatever ordering i chose. Thanks

Comment: I've tried "categories_path(@category, order: :latest)", this returns me to the index page. "categories_path(:category, order: :latest)", this also returns me to the index page. "categories_path(category, order: :latest)", this just throws errors.

Comment: categories_path will always return you to the index page

try category_path instead

Comment: Thats it!! thank you so much for your help Kamil!! One note i will mkae for anyone else reading this is that I left my albums controller how I had it originally in the beginning of my question. I changed it to the suggested way in the answer but it broke and I could not get it working. So i changed it back to how i had it originall as it was working perfect. I will say though that for the nested relationship (going into categories and displaying albums through there) aka the #categories controller, the code in the answer works perfectly. Cheers